# Build error in visual studio 2022 c++ project that is automatically generated by unreal 5.3

Tags: c#, c++, unreal

I create Games - Blank - C++ project with Unreal engine 5.3, then Unreal editor creates Visual studio 2022 c++ project automatically. After that, I closed the Unreal editor, and build the Visual Studio project without adding any line of c++ code. But the following errors occur. Please let me know what happens? and How to solve the problem?

[image]

Comment: Ignore the Intellisense errors... you have two errors in .cs files. I don't know much about C#, but could be a language version issue?

Comment: hello ChrisMM, I expect that Unreal should take care of the problem since all .cs files are created from Unreal.

Comment: ***I expect that Unreal should take care of the problem since all .cs files are created from Unreal.*** In my experience generation of code is not always that smart to be able to detect and avoid problems in future releases of dependencies. However I am in the same situation as @ChrisMM. I am a c++ programmer. I did use c# in the past but it was for a single project at work it's been like 15 years.

Comment: Looks like this  is the problem: [https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/error-compiling-the-automation-tool-after-updating-visual-studio-today-unreal-5-3-2/1393088/5](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/error-compiling-the-automation-tool-after-updating-visual-studio-today-unreal-5-3-2/1393088/5)